# C++ test exercise, variables negative conditional

Tags: c++, if-statement

The teacher said that whenever the `c` variable is negative then: "the variable `a`  is negative", but this doesn't make sense.

Is the program written in the wrong form?

In my opinion else should be part of the `if(a>0)` with `{}`. I don t know why he chose to not use it.

In conclusion, is the correct form like: `if(a>0){...}else` and than `cout`?

```
#include <iostream>`

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  int a, b, c;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;
  cin >> c;
  if (a > 0)
    if (b > 0)
      if (c > 0)
        cout << "they are all positive";
      else
        cout << "the number a is negative";
}
```

Comment: If that is actually the code you got it will print `"the number a is negative"` only if all these conditions match: `a` is larger then zero, `b` is larger then zero and `c` is equal or less than zero.

Comment: This is a typical newbie question: the indentation is very good, but there are no curly brackets and apparently the author doesn't know how to use else-clauses in nested if-loops. I'd like to reopen this question without editing it (I mean, it makes no sense editing the question into its own answer just for the sake of reopening it?) :-)

Comment: Also worth noting that `0` is not negative.

Comment: If you have 3 numbers, there are 8 combinations of "is positive" "is not positive". You have only 2 possible outputs. What's the program meant to do?

Comment: Ah ok, now I get your question. Yes in the current from the program will print `they are all positive` if all are positive, and `the number a is negative`  if `a` and `b` are positive, and `c` is zero or negative. So it should print `the numbers a and b are positive and c is negative or zero` instead to be correct.

Comment: And yes if the statement `"the number a is negative"`  should be correct it would have to be `if (a > 0) { if (b > 0) if (c > 0) cout << "they are all positive"; } else { cout << "the number a is negative"; }` or more precisely `if (a > 0) { if (b > 0) if (c > 0) cout << "they are all positive"; } else if ( a < 0 ) { cout << "the number a is negative"; }`

Comment: But for your question the `The teacher say that whenever the c value is negative it say: " the a number is negative" ` does not make sense. The claim that if `c` is negative it will print `the a number is negative` is indeed not wrong (if `a` and `b` are positive). But it won't make sense to print "`a` is negative", when `c` is negative. Could you please clarify the first sentence, what was actually said by the teacher and who wrote the shown code?

Comment: I think what the teacher says is a description of the logical failure of the shown code. (ie.. in contrast to a description of what it should do.) Please clarify what the program is supposed to do and what the teacher describes in the shown quote.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct. `else` applies to the newest `if`, so the value of `c` determines the output. (More specifically, the program will only print something when both `a` and `b` are positive.) You can test this by running the program.

The output "the number a is negative" is illogical, because that's the point of the test. The program is intentionally written incorrectly. If answers to all test questions were obvious, everybody would get the best grade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `curly brackets` otherwise `else` will only apply to the `newest if`. The program will only `print` when both `a` and `b` are `positive`.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem here is the lack of a clear specification of what the program is supposed to do. I suspect that you do have it, but without it available here I can only explain what the code is doing and how the quote from the teacher can be read as describing what the code does.

To visualise here is a modified version of your code, which is self-explaining (I hope):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  int a, b, c;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;
  cin >> c;
  if (a > 0)
    if (b > 0)
      if (c > 0)
        cout << "they are all positive"; // true
      else
        cout << "the number 'c'  is negative or zero, 'a' and 'b' are positive";
    else
      cout << "the number 'b'  is negative or zero , 'a' is positive, no idea about 'c'";
  else
    cout << "the number 'a'  is negative or zero , no idea about 'b' and 'c'";
        
}
```

I suspect that where this outputs "no idea" is where you might want to use more `if`s, in order to describe the other numbers.

Note: I stuck to your style (without `{}`). But I recommend to use them generously. In my experience it makes life easier and in my opinion makes code more readable.

I think the quote from the teacher

> whenever the c value is negative it say: " the a number is negative" but it doesn't make sense

Should be read as:

'Whenever the c value is negative (and the other two are positive) this code outputs: "the 'a' number is negative", but that doesn't make sense, because `a` is in fact positive when this output occurs.

And I agree.